# Adding Update and Delete Functionality for Database Rows to Repeater

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, sql-server

I am using a repeater to display data from SQL Server database, and have added buttons for each row in the database.

Here is the code for filling the repeater:

```
 SqlConnection connR;
    string connectionStringR = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[
        "BallinoraDBConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;
    connR = new SqlConnection(connectionStringR);
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Events", connR);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);
    Repeater1.DataSource = dt;
    Repeater1.DataBind();
```

And here is the Repeater code:

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <div>
                                <table>
                                    <tr><th><%#Eval("Event_Title")%></th><td><button>Edit</button></td><td><button>Delete</button></td></tr>
                                    <tr><td>Event Group ID</td><td><%#Eval("Event_Group_Id") %></td></tr>
                                    <tr><td>Event Type</td><td><%#Eval("Event_Type")  %></td></tr>
                                    <tr><td>Event ID</td><td><%#Eval("Event_Id")  %></td></tr>
                                    <br />
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8sWC.png) is the UI
I'm not sure where I should add the Edit and Delete code for each row because the number of events displayed is based on the number of rows in the database.

Comment: Are you just using a label for all of that content?

Comment: Simple suggestion - don't do manual markup from code behind, use Repeater and Button controls instead

Comment: @Hank The only reason I am using a label is because I got it from a previous example.

Comment: @Andrei if I use a repeater, is there a way to generate the Button controls based on the database rows too? For example, if I use a repeater and display 6 Events, could I display a 'Delete' button next to each Event which would delete that event from the database?

Comment: @user2911539, of course, you can absolutely do that with repeater or gridview. If you could not do such a common thing asp.net would be a useless tech stack, don't you think?

Comment: @Andrei I have managed to get the data displayed in a repeater, but now I'm not sure where to add the functionality to delete rows in the database. See above please.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should probably improve your question a bit and follow the tips in the comments, but what you could be aiming for to get started is something like this:

`<button onclick="delFunc('bowlingId');">Delete Bowling</button>`

This will give you a text on the button and also add a onclick event, for wich you have to write a script function. This means you have to get some Id from your query to identify each unique event in the database. When you have that you can write some code to delete a unique row, and call that function from a script on the page, how to do this depends a lot on what kind of backend you are using, but a general idea could be something like this:

```
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
  function delFunc(id) {
   $.ajax({
     method: "POST",
     url: "deleteEvent.php",
     data: id
   })
   alert('deleted '+ id +'!');
  }
 </script>
</head>
```

You will need to use [jQuery for the $.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) call to work.

Well this can hopefully get you started at least :)

Comment: Hi, I've tried to add the onclick you have mentioned above, but I am getting an error, which I have shown above in my question.

Comment: You have quotes (") in the middle of your string... this is closing the string. I suggest you read up on some very basic C# before trying anything else...

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it in **gridview**.

If you still want this to be done in asp:label then I suggest you one thing. Use anchor instead of button and link to same page with a `querystring` like below

```
lblGroupOneEvents.Text += "<div> <table> <tr><td>" + reader["Event_Title"] + "</td>" + "</tr><tr><td><a href='samepage.aspx?remove=" + reader["id"] + "'>Remove</a></td></tr></table> </div>";
```

in page load handle the delete functionality

```
if(Request.QueryString["remove"]!=null)
{
   //your delete code here
}
```

Comment: Ideally, I would want a specific "section" on the page for each Event in the table, rather than a label. I am trying to avoid using something that will display like a table, is there a way to make a gridview look un-like a table?